# I can't seem to get the Fancy Box to work in IE7

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I can't seem to get the Fancy Box to work in IE7. It just
  loads to its own page, but no box or any effects comes up.

```
jQuery("#fancybox-img").click(function() {
    jQuery('#fancybox-img').wrap(
        jQuery('<a>')
        .attr('href', jQuery(arg[0]).attr('href'))
        .addClass('cloud-zoom')
        .attr('rel', "position: 'inside'")
    );

    jQuery('.cloud-zoom').CloudZoom();
    /*jQuery("#accordion").accordion({ autoHeight: false,
        animated : false
    });*/
});
```